# Phonegap multiple apks and ipas from same code base

Tags: cordova

I have created an apk and an ipa from a phonegap project(using eclipse and xcode respectively, by copying over the www folder from android project to ios project).

This particular project was used for a single product brand.

Now, is there a way to keep the same code base and create 2 different apks and ipas that would support 2 different product brands?

The only difference between the two products would be

1. jquery mobile css theme
2. images used throughout the app
3. minor functionality changes(showing/hiding of a few UI components)

The css theme, images, all the js and html files are inside the www folder.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: icenium ide will help you acheive that but afaik it comes along with a subscription fee.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried export as apk in eclipse?